# Minimum distance between two data sets

Tags: st.statistics, tag-removed, inequalities, linear-programming, geometry

Suppose we have two sets of data, $X$ and $Y$, each of which contains
$10$ positive numbers. Now let us order the data sets $X=\left\{ x_{1},\cdots,x_{10}\right\}$,
$x_{1}\ge\cdots\ge x_{10}>0$ and $Y=\left\{ y_{1},\cdots,y_{10}\right\}$,
$y_{1}\ge\cdots\ge y_{10}>0$ and define $d:=\sum_{k=1}^{10}\left|x_{i_{k}}-y_{j_{k}}\right|$,
that is the sum of the distances of the numbers in pairs from the
two data sets. Does anyone know how to prove that $d$ achieves its minimum when $i_{k}=j_{k}=k$
for $1\le k\le10$, or is there any counter example if it is not true? Thanks.

Comment: same question was posted and was answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95546/minimum-distance-between-two-data-sets

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more general proof.

Let $x$ be any vector in $R^n$. Let $x^\downarrow$ denote the vector obtained from $x$ by sorting its entries in decreasing order, so that $x_1^\downarrow \ge x_2^\downarrow \ge \cdots \ge x_n^\downarrow$. Now, let $x, z \in R^n$, and consider $x+z$. Clearly, if we apply the *same* permutation to $x$ and $z$ separately, the entire sum $x+z$ is also permuted the same way. Hence, we may assume wlog that $x=x^\downarrow$. Now, let $x$ be as in your question above, and let $z=-y$.

Recall now the concept of [majorization](http://books.google.de/books?id=jE11p6ziLJ0C&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false). A quick calculation (also see Theorem II.4.2 of [Matrix Analysis](http://books.google.de/books?id=F4hRy1F1M6QC&dq=matrix+analysis&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s) by *R. Bhatia*) shows that
$$x^\downarrow + z^\uparrow \prec x + z$$
(since we assumed wlog that $x=x^\downarrow$); also since $y=-z$ we obtain

$$x^\downarrow - y^\downarrow \prec x - y.$$

But this majorization implies that for any *symmetric gauge function* $G$, we have
$$G(x^\downarrow-y^\downarrow) \le G(x-y).$$
This then implies the original minimization claim if we choose $G=\|\cdot\|_1$.